# Fibonacci undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass Ruby

Tags: ruby

Can someone please tell me why Im getting a ": undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)" and how can i fix it please? I would really appreciate it.

```
def fib_recursive(n)
  raise ArgumentError, "The number must be a positive integer" if n < 0
  return [] if n == 0
  return [0] if n == 1
  return [0,1] if n == 2 

  seq = fib_recursive(n - 1)
  seq << seq[-2] + seq[-1]
  puts seq
end
```

fib_recursive(5)

but using this method works? sorry i'm really new in Ruby

```
def fib_recursive(n)
  raise ArgumentError, "The number must be a positive integer" if n < 0
  return [] if n == 0
  return [0] if n == 1
  return [0,1] if n == 2
  seq = fib_recursive(n - 1)
  seq << seq[-2] + seq[-1]
  seq
end
```

p fib_recursive(5)

Comment: Implicit return. Check out the return value of puts.

Comment: When you report an error message you should give the line in which it occurred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without an explicit `return` statement, ruby methods return whatever is the last executed line in the method.

The top method's last line is `puts seq` ... this will output `seq` to the console BUT it returns nil.

So your `fib_recursive` returns nil for any value higher than 2.

```
  seq = fib_recursive(n - 1)
  seq << seq[-2] + seq[-1]
```

This is setting `seq` to nil, and in the next line you're doing seq[-2] and seq[-1] but seq (being nil) doesn't have a method for `[]`

So you can see why you got `"undefined method [] for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)"`

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider first the calculations performed by the second method, the one that works (for `n = 5`). (I shortened the method name to `fib` to make my drawings easier to understand.)

```
fib(5)
  seq = fib(4)
               -> fib(4)              
                    seq = fib(3)
                                 -> fib(3)
                                      seq = fib(2)
                                                   -> fib(2)              
                                          =        <-   return [0,1]
                                      seq << 0+1             
                        =        <-   return [0,1,1] 
                    seq << 1+1
      =        <-     return [0,1,1,2]
  seq << 1+2
  return [0,1,1,2,3]
```

`fib(5)` calls `fib(4)` which calls `fib(3)` which  calls `fib(2)`. `fib(2)` then returns `[0,1]` to `fib(3)` which is assigned do `fib(3)`'s variable `sec`. `fib(3)` appends `0+1` to the array `seq` and returns that value (`[0,1,1]`) to `f(4)`, where it is set equal to `f(4)`'s variable `sec`. `f(4)` then appends `1+1` to `sec` and returns that array to `fib(5)`. `fib(5)` repeats those steps and returns `[0,1,1,2,3]`, completing the calculations.

Now let's consider how the calculations are affected by changing the last statement from `sec` to `puts sec`.

```
fib(5)
  seq = fib(4)
               -> fib(4)              
                    seq = fib(3)
                                 -> fib(3)
                                      seq = fib(2)
                                                   -> fib(2)
                                          =        <-   return [0,1]
                                      seq << 0+1
                                      puts seq             
                        =        <-   return nil 
                    seq << 
                      nil[-2]+
                      nil[-1]
```

As you see `puts sec` is first executed by `fib(3)` after it has received `[0,1]` from `fib(2)`, assigned that array to its variable `sec` and appended `0+1` to `sec`. `puts sec` displays each element of `sec` on a separate line and then returns `nil` to `fib(4)`. That's because [Kernel#puts](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Kernel.html#method-i-puts) always returns `nil`.

`fib(4)` assigns its variable `sec` to `nil` and then attemps to execute
`nil << nil[-2]+nil[-1]`. Ruby's first task is to evaluate `nil[-2]` but discovers that `nil` has no method `[]`. She therefore raises a `NoMethodError` exception, displays the exception message (`NoMethodError (undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass)`) and identifies the line on which it occurred (`seq << seq[-2] + seq[-1]`).